# Facebook login crashes on cold starts

Tags: ios, facebook, memory-management, authentication, crash

I have a little trouble when implementing new Facebook Login for our app. We are using Facebook SDK v4.3 for our development. And the login/signup process crashes on devices with low memory. We suspect that the low memory constraints have caused our app to terminate when it triggered a switch to Facebook for authentication. As document in the Facebook's old SDK (link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios#login-apicalls):

> Login flows require an app switch to complete, it's possible your app gets terminated by iOS in low memory conditions or if your app does not support backgrounding.
>
> In that case, the state change handler supplied to your open call disappears.
>
> To handle that scenario explicitly assign a state change handler block to the FBSession instance any time prior to the handleOpenURL: call:

```
// During the Facebook login, your app passes control to the Facebook iOS app or Facebook in a mobile browser.
// After authentication, your app will be called back with the session information.
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url 
        sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
        annotation:(id)annotation
  {
      // Note this handler block should be the exact same as the handler passed to any open calls.
      [FBSession.activeSession setStateChangeHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

           // Retrieve the app delegate
           AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
           // Call the app delegate's sessionStateChanged:state:error method to handle session state changes
           [appDelegate sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
      }];
      return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
  }
```

Unfortunately, the new Facebook SDK deprecated FBSession.activeSession and its stateChangeHandler. I followed the custom UI FBLogin button for my app, here is my appDelegate code

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                      openURL:url
                                            sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                   annotation:annotation];
}
```

The code works fine and executes perfectly under normal condition. However, it behave oddly under cold starts (due to low memory). So my question would be: How do we prevent this? Is there an equivalent handler for the new SDK?

PS. I did my job in managing the device's memory. But it still didn't work under this stressed conditions.

**Edit: All I want is to grab the user's basic information on success. Therefore, I did not need keep track (or have the need to) of the access token. This is the block of code that I use to invoke login**

```
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            [ErrorMessageDisplay displayErrorAlertOnViewController:self withTitle:FB_LOGIN_ERROR_TITLE andMessage:FB_LOGIN_ERROR_MESSAGE];
            [self.loginView enableLoginButtons];
        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            [ErrorMessageDisplay displayErrorAlertOnViewController:self withTitle:FB_LOGIN_CANCEL_TITLE andMessage:FB_LOGIN_CANCEL_MESSAGE];
            [self.loginView enableLoginButtons];
        } else {
            [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id user, NSError *error) {
                //TODO do something in here
            }];
        }
    }];
```

Using the part of the code, the app still freeze on low memory after authenticated using facebook. In fact, the handler did not get call **at all**

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you follow all the steps in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started including connecting the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` of the `FBSDKApplicationDelegate` (in addition to the openURL:)
2. Check `FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken` in an appropriate area of your app (such as viewDidLoad, as described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/). This will be set for you by the SDK in cases of a "cold start" of your app.

Comment: I tried all of the above and added the codes in both didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and applicationDidBecomeActive. I think that's why it works for all of the phones, except the one with very low memory. Do you happen to know any other things that could help?

Comment: Are you saying `currentAccessToken` is still nil? If so, please file a bug with code samples to developers.facebook.com/bugs. Otherwise, you should use currentAccessToken even if your app had been evicted from memory.

Comment: We don't use the currentAccessToken at all actually in our app as we have no need for it. Since I cannot post the code here, please read it in my edit

Comment: In fact, this block did not get call at all: `FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        //Code block
    }];`

Comment: You should use `currentAccessToken` to determine if the user has logged in. Assuming your login code is in a view controller that is opened when your app launches (or resume from a cold start) , check it at viewDidLoad per my earlier comment and do the same work you have inside the handler block of the login manager (i.e., you probably want to extract that to a single method).

Let me know if you can file a bug or provide a complete project sample as that might help clarify things too.

Comment: I can provide the login code. As well the the relevant login code. Would that help? and where do I send it to?